# Why I using EasyTracker to send action 100 times, but Google Analytics just show I have send 20 times?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Why, when I use EasyTracker to send action 100 times, does Google Analytics just show I have sent only 20 times?

The code I use to send an action by easyTracker is below. The Log shows that it ran 100 times, but the background GA just shows 20 times. Why?

```
Log.d(TAG,"onMultiWindowModeChanged#EasyTracker->name:"+getPackageName()+" ,imei:"+imei);
        // MapBuilder.createEvent().build() returns a Map of event fields and values
        // that are set and sent with the hit.
        easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
            .createEvent("MultiWindow",   // Event category (required)
                         getPackageName(),  // Event action (required)
                         imei,   // Event label
                         null)            // Event value
            .build()
        );
```

Comment: Did you think about the limitations of sending hits? You only have an x amount of tokens for sending data within a time period. Also, a session has a limitation to how many hits it can send to Analytics.

Comment: I use the Google Analysis SDK V3, how should I set the limitation of session?

Comment: From: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/limits-quotas.

Android SDK

For each tracker instance on a device, each app instance starts with 60 hits that are replenished at a rate of 1 hit every 2 seconds. Applies to all hits except for ecommerce (item or transaction).

iOS SDK

Each property starts with 60 hits that are replenished at a rate of 1 hit every 2 seconds. Applies to all hits except for ecommerce (item or transaction).